# Simplest way to create the flow: (HTTP Request) --> response stored in an s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to store HTTP responses in S3 objects.
I can build a simple lambda to fetch the HTTP request and store the response in S3, however, I don't currently use anything but S3 in AWS. I'm hoping such a scenario might have something built in or ready to use.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Are you saying that an HTTP request is being sent _somewhere_ and you would like to store the contents of that request to an Amazon S3 object? Or are you saying that you have a list of URLs and you want to send a request for that URL (eg a web page) and store the result of the request in an S3 object? Also, why do you refer to an "s3 bucket presigned url"? Please Edit your question to make your requirements clearer.

Comment: To what (or which service) is the http call directed? Are you talking about CloudFront, S3, LB?

Comment: @David generic HTTP request.

Comment: There is no AWS-provided service for making HTTP calls and storing the response in S3. You would need to build it yourself.